# naturalearth sqlite db not loading into qgis 2.2

Tags: qgis, sqlite, natural-earth

I downloaded the naturalearthdatabase in sqlite-format (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/, the downloadlink goes to http://kelso.it/x/nesqlite), but qgis 2.2 (running under win 7 64bit) does not load it ("unexpected error"), but I can open the db in sqlitequi. Any ideas whats wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this bug. Opening the layers with `Add Vector layer`still works (at least in QGIS 2.0).

This might be an issue with sqlite versions mismatch. The database is 2 years old, and spatialite is in a process of heavy development.

It might be worth a bug report, but I don't know who can resolve this: QGIS/Spatialite/NaturalEarth?

The answer to this question gives some more explanation and workarounds:

[How do I use the Natural Earth SQLite DB with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78172/how-do-i-use-the-natural-earth-sqlite-db-with-qgis)

Comment: thanks for explaining this. Add Vector layer under qgis 2.2 does not work for me..

Comment: Why not? You have to select one of the available layers, then hit OK.

Comment: oh, you are right, it works . ( I tried to use add vector layer and selected database instead of file).